# html - video box doesn't appear in safari

Tags: html, css

I have pretty simple code that contain two boxes one beside the other here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/tjV3U/.
The first box contain some text, and the other one contain a video (code: `<video width="..." src="..." controls=""></video>`)
in google chrome the code works well, also in firefox and internet explorer, but unfortunately it doesn't work in safari and I can't figure out the solution for this problem.
Just try to open the fiddle link in google chrome and in safari.

Comment: What version of Safari are you using?  The video shows up fine for me on Safari 6 on MacOS 10.7.

Comment: please read this link.... http://www.tastyapps.com/videobox-help/

Answer (score 0):

Safari supports only the MP4 format for video players. not WebM and Ogg.

Comment: And my video is MP4:( can't you see that from my code in the fiddle link?

Comment: @user2975646 which safari build do yo have?